# How to run a C script code in a C++ program

Tags: c++, c

I would like to run a what I called "script C code" from string in my C++ program, for exemple :

```
int main(){
    // my string (from a file): printf("Hello, Stackoverflow!")
    RunScript(MyStringScript);
    return 0;
}
```

I could use clang or other, but I have no idea how to do that...

PS: The goal is not to make a C interpreter, no, just run a C code to broaden my program.

Comment: Unfortunately, there’s no clean way to do this. What you’d need here is essentially a C interpreter.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ are _scripting languages_.

Comment: @user0042 - There's nothing in the standard the precludes an implementation from implementing C like a scripting language. It's just not common, and frankly the distinction is somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: @StoryTeller You mean something like emscripten does?

Comment: @user0042 - I mean something like [Ch](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/ch-a-cc-interpreter-for-script-computing/184402054).

Comment: @user0042 - I didn't say C was a scripting language.

Comment: @MinoTaure Well, as you already know that, how do you imagine you can achieve what you're asking for in an easy way?

Comment: I don't think Mino is expecting it to be easy. They wouldn't have asked the question and probably would have already written the program if they did.

Comment: @user4581301 Then he's either asking for a 3rd party resource or a way too broad question.

Comment: Do not think that I did not seek, I preferred posed a question with a wide choice of answer for a greater opening to new possibilities

Comment: Have you considered plugins (delayed-load .so or .dll)s?  You compile them separately, and use your system's dynamic shared library features to use them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for reaching your goal, is to use a C interpreter library.

For example you can use this one: https://github.com/jpoirier/picoc

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is what I need I things

Comment: @user4581301 You are right, extended my answer a little bit. Mino Taure, if my answer helped you please leave an upvote and click to the accept answer button, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with libjit. Because you are then running the system compiler, any ISO C/C++ code can be compiled (picoc is not fully ISO C complete)

**Obligatory disclaimer: Running user supplied code at runtime is very dangerous unless it is properly sandboxed. Maybe consider doing it another way.**

Comment: Ok, I will see and will take precautions